# SWIG: wchar_t support for Java

Tags: java, c#, python, c++, swig

I use `%include wchar.i` in C# and it seems to work correctly for all `wchar_t` values and arrays mapping to C#'s `string`. Swig's library for Python also contains the typemaps for `wchar_t` in `wchar.i` file.

Java's library doesn't have `wchar.i`. What's the reason for that? And also how I can achieve type mapping from `wchar_t` types in C++ to `String` in Java?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using c++, than you can try with `std::wstring` as it has typemaps for all: C#, Python and Java. It is in `std_wstring.i`

Comment: I can't use STL for various reasons. But thanks for reply

Comment: after some searching i found that wchar length depends, on one platform it have 2bits and can be directly converted to jchar, on other have 4bits and need other threating, more about wchar c++->Java you can find in this thread: [https://community.oracle.com/message/6466730#6466730](https://community.oracle.com/message/6466730#6466730)